# Git rebase workflow - adding bugfixes to a "stable" branch

Tags: git

For this project I'm working on, we're using a fairly standard git rebase workflow. That is, we'll do all of our work in a `feature` branch. After a feature is ready to be tested, someone else will:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

We also have a `stable` branch, which is basically a less bleeding-edge copy of `master`. After the changes in `master` have been thoroughly tested by others, someone will then:

```
git checkout stable
git merge master
```

The problem I'm having is the following situation:

1. `master` has many new commits compared to `stable`, since a new feature has just been pushed out for testing.
2. The commits in `master` are not at all ready to be merged into `stable`.
3. A bug is discovered in `stable`, and needs to be fixed right away.

I can't simply add the bugfix to `stable` and then rebase `master` on top of it, as others have checked out `master`. I can't add the bugfix to `master` and then merge it into `stable`, because `master` contains commits which aren't at all ready for use. And, finally, I don't want to just add the bugfix to the end of both `stable` and `master`, because this would make the next `git checkout stable && git merge master` break.

How can I adjust my workflow to accommodate this situation? I'd like to avoid duplicating commits (i.e., `stable` ending up with the "same commit" twice, with different commit hashes), or merge commits.

Currently, since this situation doesn't come up very often, I just rebase `master` onto `stable` and make sure everyone else that has it checked out is aware. I'm wondering if there's a more clean way to achieve this, however.

Comment: You say the bug is discovered in `stable`, but only mention code reaching stable by being merged from `master`.  As I read it, this implies the bug was introduced in some commit to `master` before its last merge to `stable`. Is this correct?

Comment: Right. In theory, all bugs should be fixed in master before being merged into stable. However, there's never "no bugs," so sometimes they get merged in and then we proceed with development on `master` before they are detected.

Comment: From comments, you don't want merge commits in master, is it merge commits from anything but `feature` you're trying to avoid, or only merge commits from `stable`? ... ah, ok, "rebase workflow", all merges from `feature` to `master` are fast-forward?

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid all merge commits, if possible. However, merge commits from `stable` are less ugly (IMO) than merge commits from `feature.` Under normal circumstances (this is a bit of a weird situation that doesn't come up very often), every single merge I do between any two branches is a fast-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way, or I hope it will seem easy after a bit of study, that avoids the merge commits.

From text and comments I see you're doing the marching-ants trick with `master` and `stable`, where the only operation (at least usually) permitted on either of them is a fast-forward merge:

```
...--X--...S                        stable
            \
             m--...--M              master
                      \
                       f--...--F    feature
```

What I suggest follows, bear with me when you get to the ugly-looking result of this first part:

```
git checkout master  -B m-temp   # let's do this with nonce names at first
git revert X
# (maybe **amend** the commit to what X should have been here)

git checkout stable  -B s-temp 
git cherry-pick m-temp

git checkout feature -B f-temp
git cherry-pick m-temp
```

producing:

```
...--X--...S---X''                         s-temp
            \
             m--...--M---X'                m-temp
                      \
                       f--...--F---X'''    f-temp
```

and all your branches have exactly one fix for X on them.  This looks like a mess, but

notice what a fast-forward merge really **is**. When it's time to catch stable up to master, you can do it correctly with either of

```
git checkout s-temp            # the slow way
git reset --hard @{1}          # . (reset one commit from s-temp, i.e. to S)
git merge m-temp               # .
```

or get the exact same effect with:

```
git checkout -B s-temp m-temp  # exactly the same, without the rube goldberg
```

each of those producing:

```
             X''  <-- discarded cherry-pick of X'
            /        
...--X--...S---m--...--M---X'               m-temp s-temp
                        \
                         f--...--F---X'''   f-temp
```

... and your branches still all have exactly one fix for X.  When it's time to fast-forward master just do likewise, leaving X' also discarded and X''' the sole X fix in your history, or you can have your feature-branch devs rebase onto X' and discard their own X'''s

---

Git has a 'description' config item for branches.  Here's something useful to put in a post-checkout hook:

```
cat >>.git/hooks/post-checkout <<\EOF
#!/bin/sh
#
#    if there's a stored note about this checkout, show it:

# $3 = 1 for a full branch checkout
if branch=`git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` && test $3 = 1; then
        git config --get-all branch.$branch.description
fi
EOF
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

and then when you want to remind yourself of something,

```
git config --add branch.stable.description \
     "reset to commit c0ffee before merging master"
```

which makes cherry-picking any master fixes you want about as easy as can be.  When you want the note gone,

```
git config --unset branch.stable.description c0ffee
```

makes all the notes matching regex `c0ffee` go away.

Comment: This looks like a great solution! My one question is, the end result (after I eventually catch `S` up with `M`), it seems like the end result will be that the commits will be in a different order - i.e., the new commits from `M` will be inserted *before* the `X` commit in `S`. This seems like it should be "safe" to me, but just to confirm: if, after going through this process, on a client I do `git checkout stable && git pull`, will it want to merge? It seems like it should still be able to fast-forward, if I understand correctly.

Comment: To your question: no, X'' is completely discarded and (assuming you have your feature-branch devs rebase onto master as usual) no master-branch history will ever change -- the pictures above have all relevant information, commit graphs in git are not just conceptual.

Comment: Re clients pulling `stable`, ah, no, what will happen after you reset `stable` is clients who have previously pulled `X''` will get a reset warning on their next pull unless they've configured `branch.stable.rebase`. Good eyes.  It doesn't seem like much of a problem to me, nobody "should" be basing work off that, right? The fix itself, if not that exact commit, will still be on their next pull anyway.

Comment: Right, nobody should be working off of it. The only time it's pulled is on one of our servers, when we're ready to do a code move. Since the person managing this though wouldn't be any random guy, just resetting it or changing configuration on the server wouldn't be a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Make the bug fix off of `stable`, then merge it into both `stable` and `master`.

```
git checkout -b bugfix stable
# Make and commit changes
git checkout stable
git merge bugfix
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
```

That way, there's only one commit (or set of commits) with the bug fix in it so there shouldn't be conflicts when you merge `master` into `stable` later.

Comment: Or even off of `git merge-base master stable`

Comment: If I later do `git merge master` in `stable`, won't I get two copies of the "same" commit if I do this?

Comment: @jthill Assuming I understand the OP's workflow correctly, that should be equivalent to `stable`. Although, I guess it might not be if a bug fix had already been merged into stable at some point since before the last merge from master.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy I don't think so. You're not creating separate commits with the same content, you're just merging the same commit into two different branches.

Comment: It seems to work somewhat, but it creates merge commits in `master`, which I'd rather not have.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a good way of avoiding that without duplicate commits.

Comment: If merge commits aren't actually anathema this one takes the cake for sure.

Comment: @Ajedi32 the first `merge bugfix` will be fastforward, yes?  It'll take stable out of `master`s ancestry, but of course the second `merge bugfix` will link it right back in so that's all good.

Comment: @jthill Correct. Unless you explicitly give the `--no-ff` option, merging `bugfix` into `stable` will just be a fast forward.